# Mod $p$ irreducibility test proof - yet another question

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

This is the statement of the mod $p$ irreducibility theorem:

> Let $p$ be a prime and suppose that $f(x) \in \Bbb Z[x]$ with $\deg f(x) \ge 1$. Let $\bar f(x)$ be the polynomial in $\Bbb Z_p[x]$ obtained from $f(x)$ by reducing all the coefficients of $f(x)$ modulo $p$. If $\bar f(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Z_p$ and $\deg f (x) = \deg \bar f(x)$, then $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$.

The standard proof I've seen in countless places is as follows:

> If $f(x)$ is reducible over $\Bbb Q$, then $f(x) = g(x)h(x)$ with $g(x), h(x) \in \Bbb Z[x]$, and both
> $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ have degree less than that of $f(x)$. Let $\bar f(x),\bar g(x)$, and $\bar h(x)$ be the polynomials obtained from $f(x), g(x)$, and $h(x)$ by reducing all the coefficients modulo $p$. Since $\deg f(x) = \deg \bar f(x)$, we have $\deg \bar g(x) \le \deg g(x) \lt \deg\bar f(x)$ and $\deg \bar h(x) \le \deg h(x) \lt \deg \bar f(x)$. But $\bar f(x) = \bar g(x)\bar h(x)$, and this contradicts our assumption that $\bar f(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Z_p$.

My question is, why is it necessary that $p$ is prime in this proof? All of the above reasoning seems to remain valid even if $f(x)$ is reduced under modulo $n$, where $n$ is composite?

Thanks.

Comment: It might be easier to think in terms of the contrapositive, that when $f(x)$ is reducible over $\mathbb Z$, then wouldn't the image of $f(x)$ mod $n$ also be reducible?  Restricting to the prime modulus case might be appropriate for the sake of an intended application or where definitions of reducibility are only made for integral domains.

Comment: I agree with hardmath. We stick to primes here because otherwise the notion of irreducibility becomes a bit problematic. For example, in $\Bbb{Z}_6[x]$ we have "factorizations" like $$(3x+2)(2x+3)=x.$$

Comment: Bill Dubuque collected links to papers studying what can go wrong with factorization of univariate polynomials, together with an outline, somewhere on this site. I'm afraid I cannot find it now :-(